# Docker alpine-pkg-glibc error while trying to install it with armhf arch

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, arm, alpine-linux

I am installing the latest version of alpine-pkg-glibc on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ this way:

```
# Install Dependencies
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates wget \
    && wget -q -O /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub \
    && wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.29-r0/glibc-2.29-r0.apk \
    && wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.29-r0/glibc-bin-2.29-r0.apk \
    && wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.29-r0/glibc-i18n-2.29-r0.apk \
    && apk add glibc-bin-2.29-r0.apk glibc-i18n-2.29-r0.apk glibc-2.29-r0.apk
```

But I am getting this error:

```
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main/armhf/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community/armhf/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/3) Installing glibc (2.29-r0)
(2/3) Installing glibc-bin (2.29-r0)
(3/3) Installing glibc-i18n (2.29-r0)
Executing glibc-bin-2.29-r0.trigger
/usr/glibc-compat/sbin/ldconfig: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("
ERROR: glibc-bin-2.29-r0.trigger: script exited with error 2
OK: 63 MiB in 61 packages
Removing intermediate container 5d82962062fa
 ---> 524153539aee
Step 6/12 : RUN /usr/glibc-compat/bin/localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
 ---> Running in 6640abb3a3db
/usr/glibc-compat/bin/localedef: line 1: syntax error: unexpected ")"
The command '/bin/sh -c /usr/glibc-compat/bin/localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Any idea of what might be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binaries at 
https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/ are for **x86_64** only.

Although you should be able to build it for Rpi:
https://github.com/chrisanthropic/docker-alpine-rpi-glibc-builder/blob/master/Dockerfile

Alternatively if v2.22 works for you, then there's an Rpi ARM binary here:
https://github.com/armhf-docker-library/glibc/releases

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @earam. It looks strange to me that something as basic as `glibc` cannot come already compiled for ARM considering Alpine is a good fit for that. Compiling it myself is beyond the time I have available. And thanks for the link to the one already compiled. Unfortunately is quite old. I guess for the moment I will stick with Debian Slim... Thanks anyway!